# AVAssetWriter showing url error

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to write a video file created by `AVAssetWriter`, which is throwing the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVAssetWriter initWithURL:fileType:error:] invalid parameter not satisfying: [outputURL isFileURL]'

my code is as follows:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *savedVideoPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"videoOutput"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[appDelegate_.documentDirectory
    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"VideoRecording.mov"]];
NSError *error = nil;
videoWriter_ = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:url fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie error:&error];
```

Any help would be appreciable. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

1) I don't see you doing anything with that `savedVideoPath` string you went to the trouble to create in your code snippet up there.

2) And if you set a breakpoint in the code and looked in the debugger, I'm guessing you would see that your `appDelegate_.documentDirectory` is nil.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code

`NSURL *url = [NSURL -->URLWithString<---:...]`

to

`[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]`

and try again.